# Is there any way to temporarly disable IOpenFileDialog during OnFileOk?

Tags: c++, hook, openfiledialog

Im hooking into all common file dialogs using the SetSite hook.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2015/03/24/how-to-register-for-file-dialog-notifications-from-shell-namespace-extension.aspx

I want to perform lengthy operation once the selected file is ok (replace it with another file, downloaded from web).

The thing is, OnFileOk is on the main thread, making the app unresponsive.
Ive also tried running another thread and doing message pump (DoEvents) but then the dialog can be used again (browse, etc) and i dont want that.

Ive seen that sometimes the dialog disables itself (all buttons). 
Is there a way to simulate that?

Thanks

============================ EDIT =======================

meanwhile i'm doing some kind of workaround:

1. i'm doing EnableWindow(hwndDialog, false)
2. i'm downloading the file in a seperate thread
3. meanwhile i'm looping with DoEvents (yuck)
4. at the end i do EnableWindow(hwndDialog, true)

this does the trick, and i also change the cursor to "loading" (yuck) - maybe i'll add a window that says "downloading"

that's the best i could come up to :/

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, but disabling the dialog is not much better than making the app unresponsive. I think what you should do is allow the dialog to close immediately (return immediately from OnFileOk), and then spawn a thread to do the background work, perhaps disabling some controls in your window and setting the "waiting" cursor.

Comment: @user1610015 this is not quite possible, as if i let the dialog close - it will immediately open the file (which is not downloaded yet) - meaning - corrupted file will be opened (which misses the point). i prefer disabling the dialog and maybe spawning a window that says "downloading", or even change the title (which is possible)